# Angular 4 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

*in ParentComponent* =>

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: '[object Object]'.
            at viewDebugError (vendor.bundle.js:8962)
            at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (vendor.bundle.js:8940)
```

Parent component Html

```
<div>
  <app-child-widget [allItems]="allItems" (notify)="eventCalled($event)"></app-child-widget>
<div>
```

Parent component

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  returnedItems: Array<any> = [];
  allItems: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.allItems = // load from server...
  }

  eventCalled(items: Array<any>): void {
    this.returnedItems = items;
  }
}
```

Child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-widget',
  templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() notify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() private allItems: Array<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    doSomething();
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.notify.emit(allItems);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The article [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

#### Cause

Your problem is very similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44691144/2545680) but instead of updating parent property through a service you're updating it through synchronous event broadcasting. Here is the quote from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44691144/2545680):

> During digest cycle Angular performs certain operations on child
>   directives. One of such operations is updating inputs and calling
>   ngOnInit lifecycle hook on child directives/components. What's
>   important is that these operations are performed in strict order:
>
> - Update inputs
> - Call ngOnInit

So in your case Angular updated input binding `allItems` on child component, then called `onInit` on child component which caused an update to `allItems` of parent component. Now you have data inconsistency. Parent component has one value while the child another. If Angular continues synchronizing changes you'll get an infinite loop. That's why during next change detection cycle Angular detected that `allItems` was changed and thrown an error.

#### Solution

It seems that this is an application design flaw as you're updating `details` from both parent and child component. If it's not, then you can solve the problem by emitting the event asynchronously like this:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() notify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(true);
                                                        ^^^^^^-------------
```

But you have to be very careful. If you use any other hook like `ngAfterViewChecked` that is being called on every digest cycle, **you'll end up in cyclic dependency!**

Comment: will the problem be solved by asynchronous event broadcasting ? Is there anyway i can do asynchronous event broadcasting ?

Comment: simply use setTimeout, I updated the question. But the problem is actually that you're updating allItems inside the parent and a child, that's your app design flaw, think how you can redesign it

Comment: `new EventEmitter(true)`

Comment: @yurzui, just checked, it uses `setTimeout` [under the hood](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L87). It will schedule a macrotask. I'm wondering if there's any way to schedule a microtask. I tried with `promise.resolve` as it schedules a microtask but the error persisted, needs investigation

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was changing the state of my data--this answer requires you to read AngularInDepth.com explanation of digest cycle -- inside the html level, all I had to do was change the way I was handling the data like so:

```
<div>{{event.subjects.pop()}}</div>
```

into

```
<div>{{event.subjects[0]}}</div>
```

Summary: instead of popping--which returns and remove the last element of an array thus changing the state of my data-- I used the normal way of getting my **data without changing its state** thus preventing the exception.

Comment: The two are not equivalent. One returns the last and the other the first. But point taken.

Answer (score 0):

When Getting this error, you can use a `rxjs` `timer` to delay the call for a short time.

This example uses the `@angular/material` `stepper` to load a default step from the query params in the url.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  template: `
    <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
      <mat-step></mat-step>
      <mat-step></mat-step>
      <mat-step></mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('stepper', { static: true })
  private stepper: MatHorizontalStepper

  public ngOnInit() {
    timer(10).subscribe(() => {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.stepper.selectedIndex = parseInt(params.step || 0)
      })
    })
  }
}
```