# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on loadingindicator

Tags: angular

I'm getting an error in my loading indicator and I don't understand why:

> LoadingIndicatorComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'hidden: true'. Current value: 'hidden: false'.

I've got a simple loading indicator image:

```
<img class="loader" [hidden]="!isLoading" src="loading.svg" alt="Loading..." />
```

With the following code:

```
export class LoadingIndicatorComponent implements OnInit {
  public isLoading = false;
  constructor(private loader: LoadingIndicatorService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loader.IsLoading.subscribe((value) => {
      this.isLoading = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Which makes use of the following service:

```
export class LoadingIndicatorService {
  constructor() { }

  private workload = 0;
  private _loading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public readonly IsLoading: Observable<boolean> = this._loading.asObservable();

  public StartWork(): void {
    this.workload++;
    this._loading.next(this.workload > 0);
  }

  public EndWork(): void {
    this.workload--;
    this._loading.next(this.workload > 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is an very good exploration about this problem in angular. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691745/angular-4-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror/44691880#44691880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying value of `isLoading`  during change detection cycle that is causing issue. which is this line of code

```
this.loader.IsLoading.subscribe((value) => {
  this.isLoading = value;
});
```

is loading modified by you service. so you need to put work around for this

```
this.loader.IsLoading.subscribe((value) => {
 Promise.resolve(null).then(() =>  this.isLoading = value);
});
```

answer is based on this post : [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: I've come across the article you've mentioned and didn't quite get the gist of it. Will take some more time to understand it better. Your solution does the trick though:)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this type problem. Use this

```
this.loader.IsLoading.subscribe((value) => {
    setTimeout(() => this.isLoading = value, 0)
});
```

Comment: It's only a workaround and not good solution. Read this article (https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) to understand how angular's change detection works.

Comment: I think this is the right solution because here you're writing the least amount of code and getting the result you want. what's the definition of the right solution according to you? @GregorDoroschenko

Comment: Right solution would If you have explained the cause of this problem and right way how to resolve this problem. Your current answer resolves the problem, but this is a dirty workaround, which can cause more errors in the future.